# cocos2d android compile time linking not working

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to get cocos2d-android (cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1) "Helloworld" sample to run under windows. I am using latest version of cygwin along side with android ndk r6, android sdk API 8. And I tried the manual [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_1_-_How_to_Create_a_New_cocos2d-x_project_on_multi-platforms)

after a lot of challenges I am down to this problem which I think is in linking the classes at compile time. when I try to run the *build_native.sh* script I get an error stating that in *CCGL.h*, `PFNGLDELETEVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC` which is defined as extern, does not name a type.

```
//declare here while define in CCEGLView_android.cpp
extern PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC glGenVertexArraysOESEXT;
extern PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYOESPROC glBindVertexArrayOESEXT;
extern PFNGLDELETEVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC glDeleteVertexArraysOESEXT;
```

'PFNGLDELETEVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC' is declared in CCEGLView.h.

```
#if CC_TEXTURE_ATLAS_USE_VAO
  #include <EGL/egl.h>
  PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC glGenVertexArraysOESEXT = 0;
  PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYOESPROC glBindVertexArrayOESEXT = 0;
  PFNGLDELETEVERTEXARRAYSOESPROC glDeleteVertexArraysOESEXT = 0;
#endif
```

I tried to add the header address to *android.mk* under *jni* directory, to LOCAL_C_INCLUDES, as suggested [here](http://cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/15284?r=15306#message-15306),but there were no rules to make them. so can anybody help me with how to compile/link this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and using a higher version of NDK worked. Try to get the most recent version, reset the environment variables, and run build_native.sh again. 
http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html